# Json how to read array of mixed child classes?

Tags: java

I know that to construct objects from Json format I need to specify the class type. I have a parent class and multiple child classes and an array that can hold different child class objects. I want to read all the child objects in the array from Json, but how can I do that? The child classes have unique fields besides the common fields that they inherit.

Comment: I need to specify the class if I read objects using gson parser... I know only the parent class not the child class. There are different child classes objects in the same array.

Comment: Have you tried jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called polymorphic deserialization. Two popular Java libraries for JSON deserialization are Jackson and Gson.

### Jackson

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization). Start by enabling default typing. I had more luck with `@JsonTypeInfo` and adding metadata in the JSON specifying the sublclass.

### Gson

This blog [post](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson/) should be useful. Basically you use a `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` of the base class and register subclasses.